# Adding Google Game Services ANE extension with FreshPlanet Method

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flashdevelop, flash-cs6

Hey Everyone so I just wanted to share this method of adding Google Play Game Services such as High Score Leader boards etc..

To your Adobe Flash AIR Application.

Here is the Method:  https://github.com/freshplanet/ANE-Google-Play-Game-Services

Also I'm sharing this because I am having trouble implementing it to my Android AIR application using FLASH CS6 and Flash Develop AS3.

So if you have used this method or are using this method or now start using it and can correctly implement it. Please HELP me!

Here is what I have done so far to try and make it work but no success. I created a button on my main timeline and gave it an instance name of `button` then added this code the button class:

```
    import com.freshplanet.ane.AirGooglePlayGames.AirGooglePlayGames;
import com.freshplanet.ane.AirGooglePlayGames.AirGooglePlayGamesEvent;

var airGooglePlayGames:AirGooglePlayGames = AirGooglePlayGames.GetInstance();

button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, googleSignIn)



 function googleSignIn():void
{
    airGooglePlayGames.SignIn();
}
```

But i get errors such as " call to possibly undefined method getInstace with static type" etc...

Please help if anyone know how to get this started. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, thanks for sharing, however StackOverflow is a Question and Answer website, not a discussion forum or a place to promote specific works. I recommend taking this [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and consulting this [article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) relating to what is considered on-topic for this site.

Regarding the issue you briefly mentioned, I would suggest providing more information about it (including what you have attempted in your code) so that we can better help you.

Comment: Alright sorry about that. Didnt know there was a separate forum. I will update this with more complete information. Thank you.